# How to use Ember.RSVP.onerror to report exceptions from rejected promises without error handlers

Tags: ember.js, rsvp.js

I just watched this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L9OOMygo1HI) of a recent panel discussion with the ember-core framework developers.

In the video the panel members are eached asked to share one general debugging tip -- Tom Dale calls out the RSVP onerror handler which makes it possible to globally report exceptions which would have otherwise been swallowed in promises without rejection handlers.

I think this handler will answer a (somewhat confused) question I asked elsewhere on Stack Overflow.  Does anyone know how to use this handler or where the docs for it might be?

[acceptable promise pattern for 'LOUD' errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17866672/acceptable-promise-pattern-for-loud-errors/17873950#17873950)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The docs are here: https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js#error-handling

This was added around September 2013.

Comment: "Usage of RSVP.configure('onerror', yourCustomFunction); is deprecated in favor of using RSVP.on" https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js#error-handling

Comment: What's the best place to do this?

Comment: @torazaburo You can do it in an initializer.

Answer (score 3):

Hope this helps any other people wanting more with Ember errors and debugging with transpiled Ember code.

First install this: https://github.com/evanw/node-source-map-support

Then -

Template:

```
{{#if debug}}
  <script src="/browser-source-map-support.js"></script>
  <script>sourceMapSupport.install();</script>
{{/if}}
<script src="/bundle-{{ version }}.js"></script>
```

Script:

```
Ember.onerror = function (e) {
  if(debug) {
    console.log(window.sourceMapSupport.getErrorSource(e));
    console.log(e.stack);
  }
  // log error to server
};

Ember.RSVP.configure('onerror', function (e) {
  if(debug) {
    console.log(window.sourceMapSupport.getErrorSource(e));
    console.log(e.stack);
  }
  // log error to server
});
```

Debugging is easier and faster.